# Find the solution without "common sense" assumption

Tags: problem-solving

Is it possible to solve the following problem without make a "common sense" assumption?

In the year 1887, one person's age was exactly the sum of the digits of his birth's year. What was the person's age?

Just to be more clear:
With common sense I mean, for example, not to assume that a man can't live more than 120 years, for example.

Comment: Might get answers if you showed us what "common sense" assumption you had in mind, and why you make it.

Comment: OK, now, why do you make that assumption? Where do you use it?

Comment: You can (and should) use known facts (common sense) to help you solve the problem. For example, most people have a two-digit age. Start there, and proceed.

Comment: Yes! That way I had solved it. Supposing that the digit of the hundreds must be 7 or 8, and then find the numbers that fits

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because of Puzzling.SE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are referring to by "common sense" assumption. A common assumptions one would make with this problems is that the person age is within a certain range, say more than 0 and less than 100. Even without that assumption we can solve it. I think the only assumption we have to make is that his birth year was greater or equal to zero.

So let his birth year be $1000a+100b+100c+d$ with $0\leq a,b,c,d\leq9$ and $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{Z}$. Hence:

$1000a+100b+10c+d+a+b+c+d=1887$

$1001a+101b+11c+2d=1887$

As $1001\times0+101\times9+11\times9+2\times9<1997$ then $a>0$.

As $1001\times2+101\times0+11\times0+2\times0>1997$ then $a<2$, hence $a=1$.

So $101b+11c+2d=886$

As $101\times7+11\times9+2\times<886$ then $b>7$.

As $101\times9+11\times0+2\times0>886$ then $b<9$, hence $b=8$.

So $11c+2d=78$

As $11\times5+2\times9<78$ then $c>5$.

As $11\times8+2\times0>78$ then $c<8$.

If $c=7$ then we require $11\times7+2\times d=78$ which gives $d=\frac{1}{2}$ which isn't allowed as $d$ is an integer.

So $c=6$ and hence $2d=12$ and hence $d=6$.

So the man was born in $1866$ and is $21$ years old.

Update: Even if we let him be born in BCE times (and represent this by a negative value for $a$) then above rational still works.

Comment: Alternatively, if the man was born in 1870, the sum of the digits is 16, and he is 16 years old at any time in 1887 before his birthday. The question does not define what is meant by a person's age in a given year. Do you think it means the age attained on his birthday in that year?

Comment: @bof Excellent point. You've highlighted an assumption I made in my answer that I didn't realize.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid using too much "common sense" you could observe that the maximum digit sum of any year (CE) not later than 1887 is 27, so the subject was born after 1859.

Now the simplest way of proceeding is to tabulate the digit sums of years from 1860 to 1887 and the age of the subject in each of those years to deduce he was born in 1866 and is 21 years old